# How to add new SBT module in intelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I would like to add a new SBT scala module to my existing SBT scala project. When I right click on my project and select new module, I could not find sbt (but I can only find Scala).

My IntelliJ version is 2020.2

Unfortunately, I can not attach print screen.

Should I have to install something ?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ can refresh SBT setup and read in the updated setup.

So just edit your SBT configuration: add new module there, configure it as you want. Then pick SBT tab and pick refresh (the first icon from left on third picture in this section  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#sbt_structure).

After than new module should appear in IntelliJ.

Comment: I can not add a new module in the SBT configuration.

Comment: Then you would be out of luck anyway. IntelliJ allows adding new module manually, but it would be automatically removed the next time you refresh your sbt setup and synchronize. I think the same is true for every other build tool supported by IntelliJ.